# Is there already a way for subscription models? (Preferred over lightning)

Tags: lightning-network, payment, recurring-payments

Has anyone heard of a project that tries (or was successful) to make reliable subscription models possible? I mean a use case where the vendor can rely on his costumer and does not have to worry that he won't receive the money he expects. For example if your internet provider wants to make a two-year contract paid in bitcoin.

Lightning preferred, of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is bolt12.org which is already implemented in c-lightning. The spec proposal can be found at: https://github.com/lightning/bolts/pull/798

Offers allow for lightning native recurring payments which can be used for a subscription model without the necessity of a third party.

It is not yet part of the protocol but my Feeling is that it is one of the lesser controversial proposals and that we will be getting there sooner or later.